# In C#, How can I limit the number of messages received in an instance of a Service Bus Trigger Azure Function

Tags: c#, concurrency, azure-functions, limit, azure-servicebus-queues

I have this function which works as expected:

```
    [FunctionName(nameof(ListenAsync))]
    public async Task ListenAsync(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("%AzureServiceBus:EmployeeEventEntityPath%")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage[] messages,
            ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken
    )
    {
        ICollection<MessageSelectionResult<EmployeeEvent>> validEvents
            = _messageSelector.SelectValidMessages<EmployeeEvent>(messages, messageActions, cancellationToken)
                .OrderBy(x => x.ServiceBusReceivedMessage.EnqueuedTime)
                .ThenBy(x => x.ServiceBusReceivedMessage.EnqueuedSequenceNumber)
                .ToList();

        if (validEvents.Any())
        {
            await Save(validEvents, messageActions, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

However, I am concerned about two limits imposed by AirTable (where the data will be saved):

1. I can only save a maximum of 10 records at a time; and
2. Only 5 concurrent connections are allowed within 30 seconds.

So:

- Is there any way I can limit this function to injest a maximum of 10 messages at a time?
- What is the best way to allow five instances but no more to work with this queue?

Comment: This possibly could help - [Target-based scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-target-based-scaling)

Comment: host.json reference for Azure [Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#example-hostjson)

Comment: by you can ``` { "maxConcurrentCalls": 10
    }``` maximum of 10 messages

Comment: ``` "prefetchCount": 10,
      "maxConcurrentCalls": 10``` will lock the message